# How to create a custom runtime lambda function in Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to implement a custom runtime for python lambda function because I want to implement streaming response, for which I have to [make changes in the bootstrap file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html#runtimes-custom-response-streaming). I came across of two ways while exploring documentation:

1. aws [documentation to build custom runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html) : it provides the example for lambda function written in bash and not Python. I am not sure what additionaly I should do make the lambda function python.
2. deploying [lambda function as a container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html): here it does not make use of bootstrap file, on which changes are to be made so that lambda function streams the response. I dont know how to set the bootstrap as the entrypoint here.

I would appreciate if I could receive suggestions/resources on which way is the right way and what exactly to do additionally to implement the custom runtime with bootstrap file and lambda functions.